# Surprising behavior when adding timedelta to a TZ-aware datetime in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following problem. Let's start with the following TZ-aware `datetime` objects in Python:

```
first_date = datetime(2023, 11, 5, 1, 50, 0, 0, tz.gettz("US/Eastern"))
date_list =  [first_date + timedelta(minutes=5*n) for n in range(0, 4)]
```

I choose this first date specifically because date change occured on November 5th, 2023 at 02:00 AM. I was expecting the following dates in `date_list`:

```
'2023-11-05 01:50:00-04:00',
'2023-11-05 01:55:00-04:00',
'2023-11-05 01:00:00-05:00',
'2023-11-05 01:05:00-05:00'
```

Instead I've got these:

```
'2023-11-05 01:50:00-04:00',
'2023-11-05 01:55:00-04:00',
'2023-11-05 02:00:00-05:00',
'2023-11-05 02:05:00-05:00'
```

As you see, the third and fourth dates are not what I've expected. What am I missing? How can I overcome this problem? I'm using Python 3.9.

Thanks.

Francois

Comment: Do time delta math in UTC to remove daylight savings time effects.